# How do I perform a T-test from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, p-value, t-test

I want to do a t-test for the means of hourly wages of male and female staff.

```
`df1 = df[["gender","hourly_wage"]] #creating a sub-dataframe with only the columns of gender and hourly wage
staff_wages=df1.groupby(['gender']).mean() #grouping the data frame by gender and assigning it to a new variable 'staff_wages'
staff_wages.head()`
```

Truth is, I think I've got confused half way. I wanted to do a t-test so I wrote the code

```
`mean_val_salary_female = df1[staff_wages['gender'] == 'female'].mean()
mean_val_salary_female = df1[staff_wages['gender'] == 'male'].mean()

t_val, p_val = stats.ttest_ind(mean_val_salary_female, mean_val_salary_male)

# obtain a one-tail p-value
p_val /= 2

print(f"t-value: {t_val}, p-value: {p_val}")`
```

It will only return errors.

I sort of went crazy trying different things...

```
`#married_vs_dependents = df[['married', 'num_dependents', 'years_in_employment']]


#married_vs_dependents = df[['married', 'num_dependents', 'years_in_employment']]
#married_vs_dependents.head()

#my_data = df(married_vs_dependents)
#my_data.groupby('married').mean()

mean_gender = df.groupby("gender")["hourly_wage"].mean()
married_vs_dependents.head()

mean_gender.groupby('gender').mean()

mean_val_salary_female = df[staff_wages['gender'] == 'female'].mean()
mean_val_salary_female = df[staff_wages['gender'] == 'male'].mean()

#cat1 = mean_gender['male']==['cat1']
#cat2 = mean_gender['female']==['cat2']

ttest_ind(cat1['gender'], cat2['hourly_wage'])`
```

Please who can guide me to the right step to take?

Comment: where do your mean_val_salary_male come from in this line(t_val, p_val = stats.ttest_ind(mean_val_salary_female, mean_val_salary_male))???

Comment: you have two (mean_val_salary_female) but non (mean_val_salary_male)

Comment: @MehdiHamzeloee oh I see. Let me check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing *mean values* of each group as `a` and `b` parameters - that's why the error raises. Instead, you should pass *arrays*, as it is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html).

---

```py
df1 = df[["gender","hourly_wage"]]

m = df1.loc[df1["gender"].eq("male")]["hourly_wage"].to_numpy()
f = df1.loc[df1["gender"].eq("female")]["hourly_wage"].to_numpy()

stats.ttest_ind(m,f)
```